# SQL commands not available in Orientdb REST api

Tags: rest, http, orientdb

I am trying to POST commands to an Orientdb using the REST api.  When I POST the following json:

```
{
"command" : "select * from system"
}
```

I get this response:

```
    {
      "errors": [
        {
          "reason": 500,
          "content": "com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandExecutorNotFoundException: Cannot find a command executor for the command request: sql.{\n\"command\" : \"select from system\"\n}",
          "code": 500
        }
      ]

}
```

However, the command works on the url

```
http://localhost:2480/command/demo1/sql/select * from system
```

but not in json.

Comment: How do you post the request?

Comment: I use a REST client on my Mac.

Comment: Could you please try with CURL from command line? Also, what's the URL are you calling in POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible from version 2.2 of OrientDb.
Look the documentation http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/OrientDB-REST.html#command

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't realised I was on 2.1.9.  Is there any date attached to 2.2?